# Custom weight initialization tensorflow tf.layers.dense

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to set up custom initializer to `tf.layers.dense` where I initialize `kernel_initializer` with a weight matrix I already have.

```
u_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [784, 784])
first_layer_u = tf.layers.dense(X_, n_params, activation=None, 
                              kernel_initializer=u_1,
                              bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal())
```

This is throwing error saying `ValueError: If initializer is a constant, do not specify shape.`

Is it a problem to assign placeholder to `kernel_initializer` or am I missing something?

Comment: kernel_initializer is the "Initializer function function for the weight matrix", so it does not make sense to put a placeholder in there

Comment: @JonathanR Can I pass a `numpy` array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve this:

1 Create your own layer

```
  W1 = tf.Variable(YOUR_WEIGHT_MATRIX, name='Weights')
  b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([YOUR_LAYER_SIZE]), name='Biases') #or pass your own
  h1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W1), b1)
```

2 Use the `tf.constant_initializer`

```
init = tf.constant_initializer(YOUR_WEIGHT_MATRIX)
l1 = tf.layers.dense(X, o, kernel_initializer=init)
```

Comment: I get this, I thought of using `tf.layers.dense` to achieve this functionality

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to achieve it with a dense layer

Comment: Hello. I'm tf.constant_initializer(YOUR_WEIGHT_MATRIX, dtype=tf.float32) on a dense layer to initialize my weights, however, the init takes 5 seconds for 3 million weights. Using your method it takes around 4.2 seconds. Is there a faster way to do so? I only need to evaluate the training set once and save the error, and this is taking nearly 50% of the time, just to build a network, test it,and deleting it.

Comment: if you use method 2 (constant_initializer) are the weights of YOUR_WEIGHT_MATRIX updated?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can define your own initializer function. The function needs to take 3 arguments: `shape`, `dtype`, and `partition_info`. It should return a `tf.Tensor` which will be used to initialize the weight. Since you have a `numpy` array, I think you can use `tf.constant` to create this tensor. For example:

```
def custom_initializer(shape_list, dtype, partition_info):
    # Use np.ones((7, 3)) as an example
    return tf.constant(np.ones((7, 3)))
```

Then you can pass it to `kernel_initializer`. It should work if dimensions all match. I put an example on [gist](https://gist.github.com/yunhailuo/9cc0c2fa59c73942ae0cb43588d0b110) using `Estimator` to construct the model and using `LoggingTensorHook` to record `dense/kernel` at each step. You should be able to see that the weight is initiated correctly.

## Edit:

I just found that using `tf.constant_initializer` will be better. It is used in [tensorflow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables). You can do `kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.ones((7, 3)))`.

Comment: Won't making the kernel a `tf.constant` make it unlearnable -- always equal to its initial value? I doubt this is what is intended by the OP...

Comment: @mikkola I just found that there is a `tf.constant_initializer` available in TensorFlow (updated my answer). If I understand this correctly, it's used to initialize the kernel but won't "lock" it. I have only indirect evidences: 1) my gist example showed that kernel did change every step. 2) `tf.constant_initializer` is used in the [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables#sharing_variables) and I think the example does not intend to make `bias` constant.

Comment: Yes, using `tf.constant_initializer` is the right way to do this.

Comment: @mikkola Just to be clear, `tf.constant_initializer` is definitely the better way. But according to the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L211-L217), `tf.constant_initializer` returns a callable `Constant` class which actually returns `tf.constant`. The `custom_initializer` is valid if people want to do something more than `tf.constant_initializer` can do.

Comment: Im using it, however, it takes nearly 5 seconds to initialize a 3 million weights network. Is there a faster way to do so? BTW: The accepted answer takes 4 seconds, it is still too much: It's consuming 50% of my algorithm's time.

Comment: would love to see this answer with the solution in edit at the top and as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Jonathan's answer worked for me on conv as well -

```
kernel_in = np.random.uniform(100,1000,(filter_width, filter_height, input_channels, output_channels)).astype(np.float32)
init = tf.constant_initializer(kernel_in)
def model(x):
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=3, kernel_size=1, strides=1, kernel_initializer=init)
```